# How to prevent a laptop from going into sleep in Windows7 32bit in High Performance mode?

Tags: windows-7, sleep, energy-saving

When my laptop running Win7 32bit is not used, it always goes into some kind of energy saving mode.

The exact behaviour ist like this. When the computer is not use, the screen will go darker and when I press any key, it will take a few seconds before the computer becomes responsive again. Alas this also kills downloads in progress or remote sessions and is highly annoying.

My energy settings are on "High performance", where the setting for
"Energy saving mode" is "never". To make sure the "high performance" 
mode works correctly, I have reset it to default settings, which hasn't helped.

Any idea where else I could look for a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new Power Plan so create a new Plan and name it anything you like.

And change it's settings (advanced settings) like these:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

You don't need to change these settings:

[image]

and make sure to check this:

[image] .

Although you can also change existing plans but I recommend you to make a new one as it might come in handy.

Comment: I created this power plan under the name "High performance plus" and compared all options to the existing "High performance" power plan. The settings are identical. While on "High performance" the laptop always went to sleep, with the new plan now stays active.

Answer (score 0):

You could go to:

Control Panel \ All Control Panel Items \ Power Options \ Edit Plan Settings

and change "Put the computer to sleep" option to "never".

Answer (score 0):

The default settings won't do it. You need to go to control panel, hardware and sound, power options.
On my laptop I do not have the performance option, but I do have balanced power option, which has "change plan settings" beside it. Click on that that should get you to a window that has drop down lists associated with battery power and plugged in. Each of those drop downs has the setting of "never" That will get you what you need. Darn just 7 minutes too late.....

Comment: This is the setting I have. I'm running a German Windows, here "Put the computer to sleep" translates to "Energy mode after"... I have this option on "never" (and only allow the mode to adjust the screen brightness and turn off the screen). So now I'm looking for other reasons why the computer is still sleepy...

Comment: @576i - What happens when you set it not to turn off the monitor.  Does the laptop stll goes to sleep?  Verify you have followed the stpes outline in this FAQ on Microsoft's website ( http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/sleep-and-hibernation-frequently-asked-questions ) under the `How can I prevent my computer from automatically sleeping or hibernating?`

Comment: Have you tried to set everything to "never" to see the results?

Comment: I will clarify that statement. I mean "never" as the monitor as well....everything..... You may need to change something in the BIOS too, whether setting it to S3, another power setting. Did Hunters better detailed instructions help any?